# How to put a double quote within two double quotes in a batch file and how to escape double quote in VBA script file

Tags: vba, batch-file, cmd, outlook, windows-scripting

So I want to echo out a line which contains just three double quotes. If I print two double quotes it just works fine and prints it (I believe the reason is that there is a corresponding closing quote) and double quotes in multiples of 2 work just fine but I'm unable to echo an odd number of them.

And from my searching the escape sequence character for double quote is double quote itself and it isn't getting me the desired result.

The command I'm running:

```
echo         Item.Subject = Replace(Item.Subject, """, "-")>> try.xyz
```

expecting `"""` with this.

I've tried

```
"\""
"\\""
"^""
```

I am generating a bas file for importing in Outlook. And [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) has corrected my mistake in the VBA file that I'm generating too. The proper way is to print 4 double quotes to do the escaping for the double quote from VBA script point of view and hence normal printing of 4 double quotes would solve my problem. The second double quote would be to escape the third one and the first and the last are to mention the replacement string from MC ND's answer.

Thanks a lot [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) you've enlightened me. :-P

PS:
MC ND has given a much detailed explanation than this question deserved, so I extended the question.

Comment: Post your code example

Comment: Escape `)` closing parenthesis as well: `echo  Item.Subject = Replace(Item.Subject, ^""", "-"^)` results to `Item.Subject = Replace(Item.Subject, """, "-")` however target language matters: for instance, to get valid `VBScript` code snippet, use `echo  Item.Subject = Replace(Item.Subject, """", "-"^)`

Comment: I actually want to create a VBScript line which says to replace every occurrence of " with -. So I thought that the equivalent code was `Item.Subject = Replace(Item.Subject, """, "-")` . Do correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assumption*: your batch code is generating a `vbs` file (or similar)

Your problem is not to echo the three quotes. Your problem is that in VBScript a double quote enclosed in double quotes needs to be escaped (from the vbs point of view), and to do so you need to double it, that is, you need not three but four quotes, the two that delimit the string and the two that means a escaped double quote

```dos
>>"try.xyz" echo Item.Subject = Replace(Item.Subject, """", "-")
```

**note**: I've moved the redirectioin to the start of the line to avoid problems with lines that could end in digits that could be parsed as a request to redirect a specific numbered stream

---

*Assumption*: Your code is NOT generating a `vbs` file and the quote escaping is what you indicate.

Then your problem is that the odd number of quotes is fooling the batch parser that keep an unclosed string that will include the redirection inside the data to echo, instead of writing to the output file

You can change the redirection to the start of the line as in the previous sample (at in this case it will work, the `echo` is still not correct), or, you can escape (from the batch point of view) the first quote so it is not considered double quote and to end with a properly quoted string,  not including the redirection in the output

```dos
>>"try.xyz" Item.Subject = Replace(Item.Subject, """, "-")
echo Item.Subject = Replace(Item.Subject, ^""", "-") >> "try.xyz"

rem Best use both 
>>"try.xyz" Item.Subject = Replace(Item.Subject, ^""", "-")
```

Why not to escape the inner quote? As it already is inside a quoted string, the escape will fail. We can escape the first or the last (in this case), not the inner one.

---

*Assumption*: Your code is not enclosed in parenthesis (`for`, `if`, ... ) inside the batch code

Then your code do not have any other problem,BUT if the assumption is wrong, then there is an additional problem. The closing parenthesis you are echoing will be seen by the batch parser as the closing parenthesis of the current block. To avoid it, you need to escape (from the batch parser point of view) the closing parenthesis.

```dos
(
....
>>"try.xyz" echo Item.Subject = Replace(Item.Subject, """", "-"^)
....
)
```