# How to include "mailto" in body of email?

Tags: html, vba, string, email, hyperlink

I send an email through Outlook. I am trying to put an email address link within the body of the email, so that one can click on it and an email opens.
E.g. "If you have any questions, please contact us at ABC", where the "ABC" is the link that represents email address, ABC@gmail.com (not the real address).

I understand, from scouring the web, this is the syntax:

```
<a href="mailto:ABC@gmail.com\>ABC\</a>
```

I borrowed code that uses HTML to format a message in the body of an email, and replaced a line with what I wanted.
I received a Compile Error (which I think is actually a syntax error in this case?).
When debugging, the "mailto" text was highlighted.

My insertion:

*<a href="mailto:ABC@gmail.com">ABC mailbox</a>*

```
.HTMLBody = "\<HTML\>\<BODY\>\<a href="mailto:ABC@gmail.com"\>ABC mailbox\</a>\</BODY\>\</HTML\>"
```

```vb
Sub SendEmailformattext()
'Update by Extendoffice.com
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRgEach As Range
Dim xRgVal As String
Dim xAddress As String
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim MItem As Object
On Error Resume Next
xAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select email address range", "KuTools For Excel", xAddress, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set xRg = xRg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
For Each xRgEach In xRg
    xRgVal = xRgEach.Value
    If xRgVal Like "?*@?*.?\*" Then
        Set MItem = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With MItem
            .Display
            .To = xRgVal
            .Subject = "Test"
            .HTMLBody = "\<HTML\>\<BODY\>\<a href="mailto:ABC@gmail.com"\>ABC mailbox\</a>\</BODY\>\</HTML\>"
            '.Send
        End With
    End If
Next
Set xMailOut = Nothing

UNCLASSIFIED

Set xOutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The original code worked so I know the mailto text is the problem.

Comment: Need to escape your double quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put a double quote within two double quotes in a batch file and how to escape double quote in VBA script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943606/how-to-put-a-double-quote-within-two-double-quotes-in-a-batch-file-and-how-to-es)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Chr(34)` function if you need to use double quotes in the string:

```
.HTMLBody = "\<HTML\>\<BODY\>\**<a href="& Chr(34) & "mailto:ABC@gmail.com" & Chr(34) & "\>ABC mailbox\</a>**\</BODY\>\</HTML\>"
```